# GDPR ip addresses regulations for Load balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, data-protection, gdprconsentform

We are using GCP Load balancer for our public website, which serves static assets from a bucket.

We have enabled the logging to be able to monitor requests to our website, and as default, we also see the visitor ip address.

Now I know that by GDPR 'ip addresses' are personal information, plus, we don't even use the ip address.

Can I disable only the ip tracking on load balancer?

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot disable IP address logging with Google Cloud load balancers. In your case, disable logging at the load balancer and implement your own logging (or filtering of logs) in your backends. Apache, for example, allows you to control the data logged.

Answer (score 1):

It would be best to stop it reaching your logs if you can, but that's more of a how than a why question, probably better answered on Server Fault as it's not a programming issue.

As far as the GDPR side goes, IPs are personal data, however, it's reasonable (and expected) to use them for anti-abuse and fraud prevention purposes. This is exactly the kind of things that the "legitimate interests" basis for processing is meant for, unlike all those crappy cookie banners that abuse it!

To use it safely, document (publicly, in your privacy policy) that this is what you are using the IPs for, and make sure that you have a reliable way of deleting the data after a reasonable amount of time to fulfil that kind of role, say 7-10 days.

In terms of technical solutions, you could perhaps pipe it via logstash and filter it on the fly so that the data is removed before it gets as far as being logged.

Comment: This is a good answer except for the last paragraph. Google load balancers are a managed service that implements its own logging. The only log setting is on or off.

Comment: Time to move away from Google, if it wasn’t already!